# Read integer array through white space with using limit in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, java.util.scanner

My requirement is:

The first line of the input consists of an integer n (where n>=3) denotes the size of the array. In next line there will be n integers separated by space correspond to the n elements in the array. For that I have used below code:

```
Scanner length = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Please Enter Length of Aarry:");
         int n=length.nextInt();
         int[] numbers = new int[n];


        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);



        System.out.println("Enter the elements seperated by spaces: ");
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        StringTokenizer strToken = new StringTokenizer(input);
        int count = strToken.countTokens();
        //Reads in the numbers to the array
        System.out.println("Count: " + n);
        int[] arr = new int[n];

        for(int x = 0;x < n;x++){
            arr[x] = Integer.parseInt((String)strToken.nextElement());
            System.out.println("values are: " + arr[x]);

        }
```

But problem is : the above code will read correctly all the integers entered with white space but i would like to specify the limit for entering values also .Please help me how to achieve this.

Comment: Not clear what you want here. You want to show an error to the user if he entered too many numbers (tokens)?

Comment: @StijnGeukens I think OP wants to stop reading the input after reading `n` numbers.

Comment: @johny I think he's already doing that now but it will fail if n > count

Comment: @StijnGeukens We can input more numbers than `n` now, but only n values will be in the array `arr`. But I think OP wants to prevent us from entering more no.s than `n`.

Comment: yes , I want to show an error to the user if he entered too many numbers .

Comment: @johnny It will throw a `NoSuchElementException` if user enters less numbers than n

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to address your 'issue':

- easiest: simply don't ask for the length of the array => length = #tokens
- validate: `if (n != count) System.err.println("Invalid input...")`